# Nema17/A4988 + LED display pump, 5v circuit not complete?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, lcd, stepper-driver

I'm trying to build a [pump from Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Open-Source-Peristaltic-Pump/), with no experience at all. I appear to be pretty close but the 5V line from the Arduino does not power the driver or LCD screen via my perfboard, it works fine on a breadboard. See the complete schematic here:

[image]

The arduino is powered without USB, so the 12 current flows as intended, but the driver and LCD is not powered (via the 5v). The schematic is a bit confusing to me, I made a connection in the red highligted area in the next pic, but it isn't drawn as connected in the schematic?

[image]

And on the arduino, the two gnd pins by the 5v are greened out, what does this mean?

[image]

I also haven't tested the encoder yet, but it looks like it is not powered? Can it be powered by the data pins directly?

Appreciate any advice.

EDIT: I checked some ground connections with the multimeter, the following are connected:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Beware that much of the material on sites like instructables is of dubious quality.  You should not be powering a motor driver through an Arduino.  Whoever wrote this seems to have proposed some goofy power supply scheme involving unwise and unnecessary modifications to the Arduino board.

Comment: It looks like your two 5 V circuits are isolated from each other (red lines?).

Comment: It looks like that in the schematic, but I soldered a connection where I highlighted in red marker in pic #2. Or did you mean they are still isolated? @ChrisStratton I can imagine. This was an official university student competition (IGEM) project, I assumed they had proper supervision, maybe not. I still want it to work though.. I have seen a ton of builds where the driver is powered from arduino though. If you google a4988 nema17 arduino.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you made that connection.

Comment: References to a "schematic" are in error because you don't have one - you have an unlabeled pictogram.  That right there is a huge red flag as it makes the sanity of the design hard to review.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your input, maybe sketch would be better wording on my part, sorry. This is my very first project and I weren't aware of these red flags. I also thought it was very similar to the more common builds using a stepping motor and A4988 to run a peristaltic pump without any LCD display + encoder.